# What is the difference between sampling variation and sampling error?

Tags: sample

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iN-77YVqLDw&t=312s) and resampling from a sample (bootstrapping).

He refers to both sampling variation and sampling error.

What is the difference between these two terms? Is sampling variation the concept that there is difference between the samples, while the sampling error is a value?